# How do I ensure C#'s Process.Start will expand environment variables?

Tags: c#, environment-variables, filenames, process.start

I'm attempting to create a process like so:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = @"%red_root%\bin\texturepreviewer.exe",
    UseShellExecute = true
};

var process = Process.Start(psi);
process.WaitForExit();
```

Now the environment variable "red_root" definitely exists in the spawned process' environment variables, but the execute doesn't seem to expand the environment variable and so the file isn't found. How can I get the Process.Start to expand the environment variable in the file name?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [**`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) method should help here.

> Replaces the name of each environment
>   variable embedded in the specified
>   string with the string equivalent of
>   the value of the variable, then
>   returns the resulting string.

```
string unexpandedPath = "%red_root%\\bin\\texturepreviewer.exe";   
psi.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(unexpandedPath);
```

Comment: Looks like this method has been around since .NET 1.1 so it's pretty safe to use nowadays.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable ("red_root", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)` ?