# Why can't i use this code to make a minecraft launcher in c#?

Tags: c#

I have searched everywhere to find out how to make a custom minecraft launcher. I managed to create this code, which should work, but sadly it does not. I login but it never starts, however for a second I get the loading ring next to my mouse. This is my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
// Enter in the command line arguments, everything you would enter after the executable name itself
start.Arguments = @"-Xmx1G -Djava.library.path=%APPDATA%\.minecraft\versions\1.6.2\1.6.2-natives -cp %APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\argo\argo\2.25_fixed\argo-2.25_fixed.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.47\bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\14.0\guava-14.0.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.2\gson-2.2.2.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.0\lwjgl-2.9.0.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.0\lwjgl_util-2.9.0.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\versions\1.6.2\1.6.2.jar net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username playername --session token:"+ words[3] + @":" + words[4]+ @" --version 1.6.2 --gameDir %APPDATA%\.minecraft --assetsDir %APPDATA%\.minecraft\assets";
start.FileName = @"c:\Program Files (x86)\java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe";
// Do you want to show a console window?
start.CreateNoWindow = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(start);
```

This just does the loading ring by my mouse for a second, then nothing opens. No logs, crashes, errors, nothing wrong. This is Visual c# compiled on Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: For the sake of readability: You can put each single argument in a `List<string>`, then use `String.Join()` to combine it with a space character as separator.

Comment: Are you sure the command and arguments are correct? Have you tried to run it from command line?

Comment: Antonio: I have not tried yet. I am about to try right now.

Comment: Antonio: I checked in command line and the command works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments you are giving have an environment variable in them - `%APPDATA%`.

The command line will expand this by default, but the .net library won't.

See [How do I ensure c# Process.Start will expand environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388639/how-do-i-ensure-c-sharp-process-start-will-expand-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

As Pete Kirkham mentioned you need to set up environment variable.
You can set it before starting the Process like:

```
var appDataPath = "your path";
start.EnvironmentVariables.Add("APPDATA", appDataPath);
```

Comment: How am I supposed to check the user's AppData path then?

Comment: OK. Found that out but I get an error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'APPDATA'  Key being added: 'APPDATA'